# TypeError: Result of expression 'Object.freeze' [undefined] is not a function ? IN SAFARI ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, reactjs, bundle

I am using Reactjs for my ecommerce project.

Everything is going well until i tested In safari.

I am getting this error "TypeError: Result of expression 'Object.freeze' [undefined] is not a function ?"

I am using webpack and the following is the error line:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      Object.freeze(emptyObject);
     }
```

The website works perfectly and renders properly on other browsers (Chrome, chromium, and Firefox")

I have the problem in ipad too. Has anyone faced this issue ? Any suggestion to fix this will be awesome.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but how can the line you posted be causing the error? `process.env` is a Node thing, Safari would never even see that part of your script.

Comment: Well, i am not sure , i am new to using JavaScript and React. I tried running my site in all browsers , only safari is producing this. Do you want any logs you want me to post ? i am not being able to figure out what went wrong .

Comment: Any luck with this? Did you manage to solve it? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: which version of safari are you using ? I get this issue with older obsolete version of safari only. i think 5< version